# Put field's value on ahref

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, field, odoo-14

everyone.

**i added a field in res.partner called x_link**

x_link = fields.Char(String="Link")

**i want to add a buttom in portal_sidebar, with href = " value of x_link " .**

**Every partner has his own link that refers to another website account for exemple**
x_link of partner 1 contains facebook/jack
x_link of partner 2 contains Exemple/David ... etc

**i tried :**

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-block " t-attf-href = "{{o.res.partner.x_link}}" > My link</a>
```

and

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-block " t-attf-href = "{{partner.x_link}}" > My link</a>
```

and

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-block " t-attf-href = "{{res.partner.x_link}}" > My link</a>
```

and

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-block " t-attf-href = "{{o.res.partner_id.x_link}}" > My link</a>
```

and

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-block " t-attf-href = "{{partner_id.x_link}}" > My link</a>
```

and

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-block " t-attf-href = "{{res.partner_id.x_link}}" > My link</a>
```

**but i get error and when i tried :**

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-block " t-attf-href = "{{x_link}}" > My link</a>
```

**the page refresh but don't redirect me to the website that x_link contains
Thanks for helping me**

Comment: Can you specify in which portal_sidebar you have put the button , because every module has it's sidebar and controller to pass the values.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Try using <a> tag it worked for me 
<a target="new" t-attf-href="{{partner.x_link}}"><i class="fa fa-file-text"/></a>
but make sure the partner have partner object like first check if partner.name is coming
if partner don't have then whatever the object(model object) is used. use object.partner_id.link as in most module other than partner the partner_id is used to relate to Partner module

Comment: @MuhammadYusuf i got same error **AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'x_link'**

Comment: @Saumilgauswami i want to put the button on the side_bar of the module "portal" so in the left sidebar, i want my client has a button wich refer to his specefic account of an another website, so i inherited the template:"portal.portal_record_sidebar" when i added the field i get that error : **'AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'x_link''**

Comment: thanks all, the correct form was 't-attf-href = "{{user_id.partner_id.x_link}}"' instead of what i was trying thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sending you snippet that working for me for email link.

```
<a t-attf-href="mailto:{{res_company.email}}"><t t-esc="res_company.email"/></a>
```

So I see you already tried above quotes. So here in my example there is res_company variable can be accessible. So, Please check at your end that your which variable is accessible.
Because as i see you tried with a different like `o.res.partner_id` and directly `partner_id` etc. So, please check appropriate variable that accessible.

Comment: exactly, it worked when i searched more and found that i should do 't-attf-href = "{{user_id.partner_id.x_link}}"' instead of what i was trying, thank you so much